# How to write TreeMap into a .txt file?

Tags: java, file-io, nio, treemap

I'm new to this forum, so please let me know if I'm not posting this in the correct place. I've been trying to write a simple program that creates a list of contacts and sorts them by last names. However, I'm having some difficulty saving this `TreeMap` list into a `.txt` file.

Could anyone give me some suggestions?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.*;

public class ContactList 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
        TreeMap <String, List<String>> lastName = new TreeMap <String, List<String>>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice;
        int secondChoice;
        boolean exit = true;
        int i = 0;
        System.out.println("Would you like to add a contact? Type 1 for yes");
        choice = input.nextInt();
        if(choice == 1)
        {
            while(exit == true)
            { 
                // try adding a second tree map
                List <String> array = new ArrayList <String>();
                System.out.println("key " + lastName.isEmpty());
                System.out.println("Plese add first name");
                array.add(input.next());
                System.out.println("Plese add phone number");
                array.add(input.next());
                System.out.println("Plese add email address");
                array.add(input.next());
                System.out.println("Plese add last name");
                String last = input.next();
                lastName.put(last, array);          
                System.out.println("This is what you just entered: " + lastName);
                System.out.println("\nWould you like to add another contact?"
                        + " Type 1 for yes - 2 for no");
                secondChoice = input.nextInt();
                if(secondChoice == 1)
                {
                    exit = true;
                    String hold = lastName.toString();
                    System.out.println(hold);      
                }
                else
                {                        
                    for (Map.Entry product : lastName.entrySet())
                    {
                        System.out.println(product.getKey() + " : " + product.getValue());                                                
                    }
                    **File f1 = new File("Contacts.txt");
                    System.out.println("\nLoading contacts into Contacts.txt ...");
                    BufferedWriter outputWriter = null;
                    outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f1));
                    for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : lastName.entrySet())
                    { 
                        String key = entry.getKey();
                        List<String> value = entry.getValue();
                        outputWriter.write(key + value);  
                    }
                    **System.out.println("File location: " + f1.getAbsolutePath());****
                    exit = false;
                    input.close();               
                } 
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Thank you for using my program");
            exit = false;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works.  As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, ***not a help forum***.  Questions of the form _"I want to do X, please help me"_ are considered off-topic.
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: You should do some research on **serialization**, that would probably get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Use something like jackson to convert to json and write that to the file.

Comment: Hi Kyle, you said you have some difficulty, but you did not said what exactly is the problem with your code. You have to be specific, because we do not know what you expect from your code. Does `txt` file has to be human readable?

Answer (score 1):

Add `outputWriter.flush()`

Update code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ContactList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            TreeMap<String, List<String>> lastName = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>();
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int choice;
            int secondChoice;
            boolean exit = true;
            int i = 0;
            System.out.println("Would you like to add a contact?" + " Type 1 for yes");
            choice = input.nextInt();
            if (choice == 1) {
                while (exit == true) {
                    // try adding a second tree map
                    List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
                    System.out.println("key " + lastName.isEmpty());
                    System.out.println("Plese add first name");
                    array.add(input.next());
                    System.out.println("Plese add phone number");
                    array.add(input.next());
                    System.out.println("Plese add email address");
                    array.add(input.next());
                    System.out.println("Plese add last name");
                    String last = input.next();
                    lastName.put(last, array);
                    System.out.println("This is what you just entered: " + lastName);

                    System.out.println("\nWould you like to add another contact?" + " Type 1 for yes - 2 for no");
                    secondChoice = input.nextInt();
                    if (secondChoice == 1) {
                        exit = true;
                        String hold = lastName.toString();
                        System.out.println(hold);
                    } else {
                        for (Map.Entry product : lastName.entrySet()) {
                            System.out.println(product.getKey() + " : " + product.getValue());
                        }

                        File f1 = new File("Contacts.txt");
                        System.out.println("\nLoading contacts into Contacts.txt ...");
                        BufferedWriter outputWriter = null;
                        outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f1));
                        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : lastName.entrySet()) {
                            String key = entry.getKey();
                            List<String> value = entry.getValue();
                            outputWriter.write(key + value);
                        }
                        System.out.println("File location: " + f1.getAbsolutePath());
                        exit = false;
                        input.close();
                        outputWriter.flush();
                        outputWriter.close();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Thank you for using my program");
                exit = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its important to close a resource after using it. In the post's code the io objects `BufferedWriter` and `FileWriter` are used and they need to be closed after they are used. In this application the writing to text file is a simple output operation and a resource like a `BufferedWriter` is used to write large amount of data or over a network efficiently.

One can use `PrintWriter` for a simple writing to a text file like in this example. `PrintWriter` has a `println` method which writes a `String` line and at the end of the line adds a line-terminator. This means the output file will have contact details written as one line per contact.

Here is the code:

```
String fileName = "Contacts.txt";
System.out.println("\nLoading contacts into " + fileName + "...");
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName);
for (Map.Entry product : lastName.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(product.getKey() + " : " + product.getValue());
    writer.println(product.getKey() + ", " + product.getValue());
}
writer.close(); // Important: close the io resource after using it.
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I'll keep that in mind for future projects. Will writing out BufferedWriter for simple operations actually hinder performance?

Comment: I don't know really (I think not). Checkout various options ([Oracle Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html)) one has using i_o_ related classes and how they are useful in various situations In general, one will gain knowledge about such things with experience.